# TeamCity running Powershell script, but failing to execute a batch file

Tags: powershell, deployment, teamcity

I am currently in the process of implementing a deployment method using Teamcity, which runs a Powershell script on my Build Agent, which then configures my Production environment etc.

I have a problem with the Powershell script though, in that it can't seem to run the batch file from it.

The script runs perfectly if I run it manually, it only fails when run via TeamCity.

In the build log I am getting the error:

```
'myBatchFile.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The batch file and the powershell script are in the same directory and the batch file is called as such:

```
cmd /c Deploy.bat
```

I have my TeamCity configuration set up to have the build step for this as:

- Script: File
- ScriptExecutionMode: Execute script with -File argument
- Script Arguments: None
- Additional CMD line params: None

I had originally not used the cmd to try to execute the batch file, but executing the batch file like `.\Deploy.bat` did not seem to work either.

Is there an additional thing I need to set up in order to get the batch file to run?  The rest of the script runs fine, just the call to the batch that doesn't.

Comment: where you put Deploy.bat?

Comment: The Deploy.bat and the powershell script are both in the same folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a wild stab as it's difficult to predict what's happening, but from the description it seems like the path is been altered in the script and it's also dynamic as TeamCity creates temp directories, but if you replace:

```
cmd /c Deploy.bat
```

with

```
cmd /c "$(Split-Path $myinvocation.MyCommand.Path)\Deploy.bat"
```

then I think this will be able to located the deploy script.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: thank you, this fixed it for my powershell script.  Just need to fix the new problems it created in the batch file ;)

Comment: lol, that's the fun part of IT, you fix one thing and something else breaks. :-)
Let me know if you need any help on that part as well.